# Can't we include .c file?

Tags: c++, c, include

Today I had an interview there they asked me can we include `.c file` to a source file?
I said `yes`. Because few years back I saw the same in some project where they have include `.c file`. But just now I was trying the same.

**abc.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void abc()
{ printf("From ABC() \n"); }
```

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "abc.c"
int main()
{   void abc();
    return 0;
}
```

Getting an error:

> `D:\Embedded\...\abc.c :- multiple definition of 'abc'`

Where is it going wrong?

I wrote an abc.h file (the body of abc.h is `{ extern void abc(void); }`),
and included the file in `abc.c` (commenting out `#include abc.c`). Worked fine.

Comment: ("Worked fine" *with* warnings enabled?)

Comment: Well, there are multiple definitions of `abc`, just as the compiler says

Comment: Done it a lot of time, being lazy to write a makefile or atleast a script to compiler multi-file codes (when not using an IDE). When including the `.c` file just visualize that the entire contents of that file will be at that position, and visualizing that you need to adjust the re-definitions.

Comment: You could add #ifndef FILE_NAME ... #endif at start and end to make sure the file gets included only once irrespective of the compile situation. I like to include C files in my unit test main because it saves writing declarations and gives access to more things for reporting or verifying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do it as follows:

`abc.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void abc()
{printf("From ABC() \n");}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "abc.c"
int main()
{   
    abc();
    return 0;
}
```

(no need for the header file)

Then, to compile, you'd **only** compile `main.c`. **Do not** attempt to **compile both** `abc.c` and `main.c`, because then you'd have the `abc()` function defined twice.

You need to understand that `#include` is basically "copy-paste", nothing more. If you tell it `#include "abc.c"`, it will simply take the contents of `abc.c`, and "paste" them in your `main.c` file. Therefore, using the above for `main.c`, after the preprocessor processes it, your `main.c` will look like this (I'm ignoring the `#include <stdio.h>`s):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void abc()
{printf("From ABC() \n");}
int main()
{   
    abc();
    return 0;
}
```

which is a valid program.

That said you should generally not do this; you should compile all your `.c` files separately and only then link them together.

Comment: The prototype is not the issue. That won't cause a *multiple definition* error.

Comment: @houbysoft: I did the same but still the error is there. No improvement

Comment: I second @ThiefMaster. Doing the above should still result in an error, as `void abc()` is defined in two translation units: abc.c and main.c (via the include). The linker should still complain.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: whoops. Forgot to mention that he should only compile `main.c`, edited.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: if you do it in this way, you should only compile `main.c`, and not attempt to compile `abc.c` AND `main.c` and then link them together.

Comment: @houbysoft: Yes it works fine... But the anti-virus (Avast) is giving an error.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: huh? Then there's a problem with your anti-virus :)

Comment: Well, I guess that's one of the reasons why people use a different extension for files that are meant to be included and files meant to be compiled, so that the intent is clear. And of course: files meant to be included do not contain things that generate object code.

Comment: @houbysoft: How to compile the `.c` file separately? Like for `abc.c` does not have main function. so, separately how to compile `abc.c` file separately?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: you'd simply tell your compiler not to run the linker. For instance, if using `gcc`, you'd do `gcc -c abc.c`, which would create an object file `abc.o`. You'd do the same for all your `.c` files, and at the end you'd link all the `.o` files together. Check your compiler manual for details.

Answer (score 7):

Including C files is perfectly valid as long as you do not try to compile the included C file by itself and then link it together with the object file from the C file which included the other file.

If you do so you'll have the same symbol (usually a function) defined in two files which will result in the errors you posted.

If you have multiple source files you usually do not include them but compile them separately. The *linker* then merges the object files into a single executable (or library).

Answer (score 4):

You can include file with any extension.

In your program, you had re-defined `void abc();` in main (). instead just put statement `abc ();`

Comment: From the research that I have made, this is the clearest and the simplest answer to the question. Vote up!

Answer (score 2):

You can include anything you like to, the preprocessor doesn't care about the file extensions. It's only some tradition to name the headers ".h" and the source files ".c" or ".cpp".

You only have to be sure, that after compiling the whole project you don't run into linker problems (e.g. giving both "abc.c" and "main.c" to the compiler would result in multiple definitions of your function).